# How to disable the TAB bar in MS Word

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, tabs

[image]I would like to know how to disable the TAB bar in MS WORD, so that all the tabs open in the Windows taskbar, not Word's own.

Comment: What do you mean "Windows tab bar"? What version of Word are you using? Are you using the _online_ (browser-hosted) version of Word 365, or are you using the desktop (standalone) version?

Comment: desktop version. ?? the windows taskbar, i think that's the correct name

Comment: Word has not used "Multiple Document Interface" (tabbed document window) since before Word 2013. It was removed in Word 2013. You probably need to upgrade. However, you might find [this question at Microsoft's forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2010/how-can-i-open-multiple-word-2010-documents-in/ab9a7cd3-fed9-4fed-be28-bf217f96d675) to be helpful.

Comment: Gracias Fernando.  It might be helpful to provide us with a picture of what you are talking about. :)

Comment: This is Word 2016. I've uploaded a picture, as requested.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Word **never had a tabbed interface**. [MDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-document_interface) has *nothing* to do with tabs. It just means the parent window can have multiple children windows and you can show all of them at the same time or maximize to show only one. You can't do that with tabs. Each children window is switched with F6 instead of Ctrl+Tab

Comment: this is essentially the same question as [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1405093/241386). They even use the same add-on for the tab interface

Comment: @phuclv - I distinctly remember tabs in older version of Word that supported MDI. No, I never used any add-ons for that functionality.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin no. I've used all the office versions since 1995 and they never had a tabbed interface. The only tabs you get is the doomed [Windows Sets feature](https://www.howtogeek.com/352109/how-to-use-sets-in-windows-10-to-organize-apps-into-tabs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image shows that you have install [Office Tab](https://www.extendoffice.com/product/office-tab.html) add-in.

[image]

> Office Tab supports opening, viewing, editing multiple Office documents in a single tabbed window, like the web browsers - Google Chrome, Firefox and so on.
> It brings the tabbed interface to Microsoft Office 2019, 2016, 2013, 2010, 2007, 2003 and Office 365 (include Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Publisher, Access, Project and Visio).

To disable an add-in, click File -> Options -> Add-ins. The add-in will be listed on the Add-ins sections. Take note of its type. On the Manage box, select the type, click Go. Deselect the add-in, click OK.

Comment: thank you very much!